# Which is better Span that runat server or default asp lable?

Tags: asp.net, performance, html

I have a simple asp.net web page that contain a table with about 5 `TR` and each row have 2 `TD`  .. in the page load I get user data ( 5 property ) and view them in this page the following are first  2 rows :

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            FullName
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="fullNameSpan" runat="server"></span>
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>
            Username
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="userNameSpan" runat="server"></span>
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I always used `<asp:Label` to set value by code but i always notice that label converted in runtime to `span` so i decided to user `span` by making him `runat=server` to be accessed by code, so
**Which is better to use `asp:label` or `span` with `runat=server` ??**

Comment: Should you be concerned with this sort of optimization? Why don't you use MVC or plain HTML?

Comment: MVC is not the answer to every problem.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot span is a plain html but with making it server to be accessed by code ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: Whatever works best for you.

asp controls have a different object model from html controls.  There is no databinding for html controls, for instance.

**EDIT:**

Something to consider is whether or not you need a span element at all.  Span is an html element used for inline items, and canoot hold ceratin kinds of other items (such as block items).  If your html markup make sense to semantically include a span (such as you want to style the text in a specific way) then use it.

Unless you need to control attributes on the span tag, it would be better to do something like this though:

```
<span class="foo"><asp:Literal id="litFoo" runat="server" /></span>
```

You should only make an element runat="server" if you need to specifically modify the tag itself (not necessarily just it's contents).  For instance, if you need to hide the span at runtime, then you make the span `runat="server"` so you can access it's Visible property at runtime.  Otherwise, it should be left as standard html.

Comment: in my case i didn't need data binding so i think span is better

Answer (score 1):

If all your doing is displaying something then your better off using a literal tag which add's no extra markup. Infact 99% of the time literal should be used over label.

**Edit:** The performance between label/span would be so tiny, if any difference between them at all, that the only reason you would be worrying about that sort of performance was if you were facebook.