# How to show span value in asp.net pages

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a code in html like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>Full Name:&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="FullName_PDLabel"><b>--</b></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am getting value for the corresponding `span`. In my frontend, I have a button like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  onserverclick="SubmitBtn_Click" />
```

I want to show the corresponding value after clicking the `button`. How can I do that? Do I need to use JavaScript or something?

This is my submit button handler code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Handles Button1.Click
End
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532903/which-is-better-span-that-runat-server-or-default-asp-lable

Comment: what is ` corresponding value value?`.. please clear your question, what you want to do and what have you done?

Comment: do share your SubmitBtn_Click handler code.

Comment: the corresonding span id i am getting full name.i want to get that full name in my button click event

Comment: You can do three things:
1) take a label instead of span and get its value in code behind
2) take a literal instead of span and get its value in code behind
3) add `runat="server"` to your span.

Comment: can you show sample code here? please

Comment: Use `<asp:Label />` control. `Label` will be rendered as `span` on client side and can also be accessed from code-behind with `id`.

Comment: @user3252014 : added sample code

Answer (score 1):

In your .aspx page add this

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Label Text</asp:Label>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">literal text</asp:Literal>
    <span id="Span1" runat="server">Span Text</span>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

and in your code behind(.cs file) add this

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string literalValue = Literal1.Text;
            string labellValue = Label1.Text;
            string spanValue = Span1.InnerHtml;
        }
```

You'll get the values of label, literal and span in code behind on button click event in `literalValue`, `labellValue` and `spanValue`